# Correct approach to handle potentially multiple modals within a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue (2.6.10) and Bootstrap-Vue.  I have a component called `<edit-experiment-btn experiment-id="1" />` which outputs a clickable button that when clicked will open a modal containing a form.  These components are single file components, with the nested component referenced within.

```
<edit-experiment-btn experiment-id="1" />
```

Outputs a button and a hidden modal (`<b-modal>`).  When clicked the modal renders a form component.

Having multiple of these (`<edit-experiment-btn experiment-id="2" />`, `<edit-experiment-btn experiment-id="3" />`, `<edit-experiment-btn experiment-id="4" />`, ...) on screen causes problems, because it's rendering multiple modals.

Is the right thing to do here to create a modal and append it to the DOM (`body.appendChild`) and check its existence, then manipulate its attributes?  I wouldn't have thought so, but then what is the best way?

Comment: do you wan't different contents in a modal populated based on some condition, or do you want multiple simultaneously visible/open modals in addition to different content ? multiple modals per se ARE supported by [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal#multiple-modal-support)

Comment: without much more information, how about a <router-view> inside a <b-modal>, some route.push magic + params ?

Comment: I only want a single modal to be displayed.  I only actually want a single modal in the DOM at any one time.  I can code the component to switch out the modal contents (which is the same form with different values).  What I'm unsure about is whether this should be done by appending the modal DOM to the root DOM and checking for it's existence before creating another (if there were 2 components) or whether there's a better way